# Is AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator cheap enough to use often, or should it be cached?

Tags: android, performance, animation

I am creating a custom view that runs a fade-in animation of the view. (In this case, after an image is set asynchronously the image will fade in—as opposed to popping into view instantly. But this question is for Animators in general.)

In the Android Developer guides for [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml), it is recommended to load and run an animation with code like:

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(myContext,
    R.anim.property_animator);
set.setTarget(myObject);
set.start();
```

But the documentation does not suggest where to call that specifically.

For *view* inflation (layouts), it is highly recommend to avoid inflation as much as possible because it is a relatively expensive method to call.

Is it safe to use `AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator()` within the view itself, even if there are many instances of that view in the activity? In other words, is `Animator` XML loading cheap enough to inflate as needed, or should it be cached and set at the activity level instead of the more convenient, and related, view level?

(Note: I'm *not* talking about the older Android 2.x `Animation` system, but the newer Android 3.1+ `Animator` system.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have individual animations running on different views, you will need different instances of AnimatorSet to control them all.  This means you'll have to inflate them individually just like you have to inflate the different views.

You can also create the AnimatorSet objects programmatically, which likely will save a little time, but I wouldn't try to optimize that until you see that you're having performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to use as necessary.

As @doug-stevenson pointed out, you need an animator for each running animation. So you can't cache one inflated instance per activity, since each animator can only target a single view.

The inflation is sort of expensive, but the Android framework anticipated this and the (current) implementation of `loadAnimator()` uses an internal class called `ConfigurationBoundResourceCache`. As long as the user doesn't change the configuration (screen rotation, connect a device, etc.), you can call `loadAnimator()` as many times as you need and a new, easily-cloned instance from the cached inflated version is created for you. (And even if the user does change config, it will only need to re-inflate once per config change.)

Obviously, you shouldn't abuse the calls by animating hundreds of views at once, since it is cloning new objects each call and then eventually will have to run every animation you start. So there is a practical limit. But feel safe that you won't hurt performance calling `loadAnimator()` when you need to animate a reasonable number of views on the same screen.